# Setting GD::Graph chart dimension and bar sizes

Tags: perl, plot

I create the following plot with [`GD::Graph`](https://metacpan.org/pod/GD::Graph). The chart bars are way too concentrated and it's not really visible.

[image: Plot]

My expectation would be something more like this.

[image: Visible plot]

My code looks like this:

```
 my $my_graph = GD::Graph::bars->new();

 $my_graph->set(
     x_label => 'Numbers',
     y_label => 'Occurance',
     title   => 'Plot',
 ) or warn $my_graph->error;`
```

What are the settings for the plot size and for the bars size (horizontal)?

Comment: You might find the slides from my talk "[Pimp My GD::Graph -
Charts that don’t suck, in 15 easy steps](http://wellington.pm.org/archive/201002/grant-gd-graph/)" useful. In case it's not obvious, the "15 easy steps" bit was somewhat tongue-in-cheek.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The module's documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/GD::Graph) describes the following options very clearly

> **width**, **height**
>
> The width and height of the canvas in pixels Default: 400 x 300.
>
> **NB** At the moment, these are read-only options. If you want to set the size of a graph, you will have to do that with the `new` method.

and

> **bar_width**
>
> The width of a bar in pixels. Also see bar_spacing. Use bar_width If you want to have fixed-width bars, no matter how wide the chart gets. Default: as wide as possible, within the constraints of the chart size and bar_spacing setting.

I suggest that the best option for making the bars wider is to reduce their number, or to increase the width of the graph

Comment: I found in the documentation the `width` and `height`, but when I try to set them i get a warning that those are read-only variables.

Comment: @TedyGrey: The documentation (copied above) also says that they are read-only values, and must be supplied in the constructor. You need to call `GD::Graph::bars->new($width, $height)`